# Transparent App Bar Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, appbar

This will have a lot of code - my apologies but it's necessary to create a working sample.

I am creating an App Bar (top or left) for my application, and I cannot get transparency to work.  While I am able to get the form background transparent as a form using:

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
```

before InitializeComponent(), and then BackColor = Color.Transparent, the App Bar background appears to be "Control."  If I then set

```
Me.Opacity = .75
```

I receive a WndProc error "The parameter is incorrect."

If I then try to do something like

```
Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(25,0,0,0)
```

I get (basically) the same "control color" look as I do with a Transparent background.

If I try:

```
Me.Color = Color.Black
Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Black
```

I receive a similar error to the Opacity error above (a wndproc 'parameter is incorrect').

Searching has not led me anywhere useful, but I know this must be possible - the Windows taskbar is semi-transparent.  I understand that they aren't exactly the same, but there must be some way to accomplish this.

In order to get this working, you should need to simply paste the below into a new Winforms app.  I wrote custom auto-hide code, but am not including it to keep this as short as possible.  It also won't have a way to close it unless you add a context menu, etc - but probably just stop it for simplicity.

Again, my apologies for the long code, but all is required in order to get this working:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf Me_Load
    AddHandler Me.FormClosing, AddressOf Me_Closing
    Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.AllowTransparency = True
    'Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(10, Color.Black)
    'Me.BackColor = Color.Black
    'Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Black
    'Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    'Me.Opacity = 0.5
End Sub

Private Sub Me_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RegisterBar()
End Sub

Private Sub Me_Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    RegisterBar()
End Sub

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Structure RECT
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Structure APPBARDATA
    Public cbSize As Integer
    Public hWnd As IntPtr
    Public uCallbackMessage As Integer
    Public uEdge As Integer
    Public rc As RECT
    Public lParam As IntPtr
End Structure

Enum ABMsg As Integer
    ABM_NEW = 0
    ABM_REMOVE = 1
    ABM_QUERYPOS = 2
    ABM_SETPOS = 3
    ABM_GETSTATE = 4
    ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5
    ABM_ACTIVATE = 6
    ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR = 7
    ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR = 8
    ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 9
    ABM_SETSTATE = 10
End Enum

Enum ABNotify As Integer
    ABN_STATECHANGE = 0
    ABN_POSCHANGED
    ABN_FULLSCREENAPP
    ABN_WINDOWARRANGE
End Enum

Enum ABEdge As Integer
    ABE_LEFT = 0
    ABE_TOP
    ABE_RIGHT
    ABE_BOTTOM
End Enum

Private fBarRegistered As Boolean = False

<DllImport("SHELL32", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Shared Function SHAppBarMessage(dwMessage As Integer, ByRef pData As APPBARDATA) As UInteger
End Function
<DllImport("USER32")>
Private Shared Function GetSystemMetrics(Index As Integer) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function MoveWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, x As Integer, y As Integer, cx As Integer, cy As Integer, repaint As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function RegisterWindowMessage(msg As String) As Integer
End Function
Private uCallBack As Integer


Private Sub RegisterBar()
    Dim abd As New APPBARDATA()
    abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd)
    abd.hWnd = Me.Handle
    If Not fBarRegistered Then
        uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage")
        abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack

        Dim ret As UInteger = SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_NEW), abd)
        fBarRegistered = True

        ABSetPos()
    Else
        SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE), abd)
        fBarRegistered = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ABSetPos()
    Dim abd As New APPBARDATA()
    abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd)
    abd.hWnd = Me.Handle
    abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_TOP)

    If abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_LEFT) OrElse abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT) Then
        abd.rc.top = 0
        abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
        If abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_LEFT) Then
            abd.rc.left = 0
            abd.rc.right = Size.Width
        Else
            abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
            abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width

        End If
    Else
        abd.rc.left = 0
        abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
        If abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_TOP) Then
            abd.rc.top = 0
            abd.rc.bottom = Size.Height
        Else
            abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
            abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height
        End If
    End If
    ' Query the system for an approved size and position. 
    SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS), abd)

    ' Adjust the rectangle, depending on the edge to which the 
    ' appbar is anchored. 
    Select Case abd.uEdge
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_LEFT)
            abd.rc.right = abd.rc.left + Size.Width
            Exit Select
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT)
            abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width
            Exit Select
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_TOP)
            abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + Size.Height
            Exit Select
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM)
            abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height
            Exit Select
    End Select

    ' Pass the final bounding rectangle to the system. 
    SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS), abd)

    ' Move and size the appbar so that it conforms to the 
    ' bounding rectangle passed to the system. 
    MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, True)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = uCallBack Then
        Select Case m.WParam.ToInt32()
            Case CInt(ABNotify.ABN_POSCHANGED)
                ABSetPos()
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.Style = cp.Style And (Not &HC00000)
        ' WS_CAPTION
        cp.Style = cp.Style And (Not &H800000)
        ' WS_BORDER
        cp.ExStyle = &H80 Or &H8
        ' WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

I'm not sure if the answer is going to be overriding something in CreateParams, or what, but it doesn't seem to be possible with BackColor/Transparency Key, Argb, or Opacity...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Me.Opacity must have a value between 0 and 100.

Comment: How sure are you of that comment? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are right, in the designer it is between 0 and 100. For the code, you are (nearly) right. Sorry for that. Do you receive the error at compile time? If yes, try this: `Me.Opacity = 0.75F`

Comment: He isn't.  The Windows Taskbar uses a very different rendering technique to achieve transparency.  Called per-pixel alpha blending.  A natural fit for the kind of programs that use DirectX to render.  Which is not Winforms.  You can easily find cut-and-paste code to enable it in your form class as well.  But it comes with a price, you cannot use the controls in the toolbox anymore.  Consider WPF.

Comment: Setting above 1 just keeps a 1 value.  Thanks for the tip Hans, I imagine searching for per-pixel alpha blending will yield more useful results than appbar transparency.  All that gives is standard "Control" transparency hits.

Comment: @HansPassant it looks like it's going to work.  I'm having a production issue right now so I can't test it, but I found a premade at: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/pxalphablend/rgl_perpxalpha_src.zip that looks like it should work.  I'll be working on it this afternoon.  If you'd like credit, please create an answer and I'll give it to you.